# why physical address value is different depending on how it was printed

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm working with a x86 architecture. As far as I understand (and have been told) to get a physical address of allocated memory I need to do the following:

```
struct SizeAddr {
  size_t size;
  u64 addr_uint64;
  void* addr_voidp;
  unsigned long addr_ul;
};

struct SizeAddr sa;

virtAddr = kmalloc(<some size>, GFP_KERNEL);
physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);

sa.addr_uint64 = (uint64_t)physAddr;
sa.addr_voidp = (void *)physAddr;
sa.addr_ul = (unsigned long)physAddr;
```

I've decided to print out the value of the physical address, so I did the following:

```
    printk(MODULE_NAME " virtAddr(%%p)   = %p\n", virtAddr);
    printk(MODULE_NAME " physAddr(%%pap) = %pap\n", &physAddr);
    printk(MODULE_NAME " physAddr(%%llx) = %llx\n", sa.addr_uint64);
    printk(MODULE_NAME " physAddr(%%p)   = %p\n", sa.addr_voidp);
    printk(MODULE_NAME " physAddr(%%lx)  = %lx\n", sa.addr_ul);
```

Here is what I got in the log:

```
[63898.990593] my_kmodule virtAddr(%p)   = 0000000000000010
[63898.990652] my_kmodule physAddr(%pap) = ffff88020d783eb0
[63898.990711] my_kmodule physAddr(%llx) = 780000000010
[63898.990768] my_kmodule physAddr(%p)   = 0000780000000010
[63898.990827] my_kmodule physAddr(%lx)  = 780000000010
```

And this is where I'm really confused. Shouldn't all these values be the same? Why `physAddr(%pap)` is different from the rest of the values (except the virtual address, that one I understand).

Comment: You didn't show the code that assigns `sa`.

Comment: `printk` #2 is wrong. You want `physAddr` and _not_ `&physAddr`. Also, `phys_addr_t` is either `u32` or `u64`, so cast to `u64` and try `%llx` as well.

Comment: I don't know what `pap` is but the way to print a pointer value is with `printf("%p", (void*)virtAddr);`

Comment: Also, how is `%pap` not interpreted as the valid format code `%p` followed by `ap`.?  What if I want to print a pointer value followed by the literal characters `ap`?

Comment: %lx and %llx simply skip leading zeros, unlike %p. Otherwise, the last 3 physAddr values are identical.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is not a `printf` but a `printk`. One is used in user space the other is used in kernel space. To find out what `pap` is check out https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt

Comment: @BenVoigt Check out https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt

Comment: @flashburn sorry didn't notice the `k`, assumed it was a C question.

Comment: Oops, my bad. My previous comment was incorrect (re. `physAddr/&physAddr`) because `%pap` is "pass-by-reference", but the `%llx` should work [and is good cross-check]

Comment: @CraigEstey So if the code is correct, why the values are different?

Comment: @BenVoigt Just added code for sa

Comment: You didn't show the actual type of `physAddr`. It must be *phys_addr_t*.

Comment: Additionally to that, did you have any compiler warnings when compiled the code? Would be nice to see full module to understand.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I can't give you the full module code. Unfortunately it is private code, at least for the moment.

Comment: Then copy it, remove everything except the code under question, but leave enough to be full-functioning and compiling module and share. I'm pretty sure the bug is in your code beyond the lines you published. I believe if you do the module I described and test it it will work.

Answer (score -2):

A virtual address (`virtAddr`) from `kmalloc` with a value of `0x10` makes no sense. So, after that, all bets are off?

Are you sure you have `phys_addr_t physAddr` (vs. (e.g.) `phys_addr_t *`)? On the stack I presume?

The output of `%pap` looks like a [stack] virtual address rather than a physical one. So, my *original* top comment about `&physAddr/physAddr` might have some bearing depending upon your full code.

What does `printk("%p\n",&physAddr);` say? Or, `printk("%llx\n",(u64) &physAddr);`? Or, other combinations (e.g. `&virtAddr`)

Although the doc says `%pap` is okay, it also says that the default is `phys_addr_t` (i.e. `%pa`). Both *should* work [and my examination of the `printk` code *seems* to confirm this], there are only about 5 usages of `%pap` and hundreds of usages of `%pa`

I have examined the `printk` source [reexamined, actually, as I've had to do so a number of times before]. At present, I have found no discrepancies to speak of. But, the source is a bit convoluted, so I'll be continuing to do so.

---

*Side note:* This was the original post [that was getting downvoted] before the edit [with some clarification], but it's still something to try.

Now that you've added your `sa` code ...

Change:

```
struct SizeAddr
```

Into:

```
union SizeAddr
```

Add a `phys_addr_t` member and only set that [with union]. That's the more usual idiom for this. Then, you'll see which get trunc'ed and which don't. Otherwise, for struct `%llx` you'd get matching results to `%pap`.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? That would just store everything in one location.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and even as a comment on OP's code, it's of questionable quality.